# How to remove the spacing between my modal operators?

Tags: math-mode

I have two modal operators *necessary* and *possible* in my document. Since I don't really like the standard `\Diamond` from the `amssymb` package, I'm using the `fdsymbol` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}

\newcommand{\necessary}{\Box}
\newcommand{\possible}{\Diamond}

\begin{document}
\[\necessary\possible\necessary p\land q\]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there is too much spacing between the operators when one combines them:

[image: Too much spacing]

The problem isn't there when I don't use `fdsymbol`:

[image: Perfect spacing]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `\newcommand*\necessary{\mathord{\Box}}` and the same for `\possible`.

Comment: It's exactly the same, `{..}` also creates a `\mathord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\mathord{..}` or just `{..}`.

```
\newcommand*\necessary{\mathord{\Box}}
\newcommand*\possible{\mathord{\Diamond}}
```